# SQL select many to many relationship

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

I've the following schema:

```
Users
-----
id
name

Conversations
-------------
id
other

Partecipants (join table)
------------
id
user_id
conversation_id
other
```

An user can have many conversations and a conversation belongs to many users.

I need to select all the conversations of an user with a subset of other users.

My try is (do not work):

```
SELECT     *
FROM       `conversations` 
INNER JOIN `participants` ON `conversations`.`id` = `participants`.`conversation_id` 
WHERE      `participants`.`user_id` = 1 
AND         (participants.user_id IN (4,6)) 
GROUP BY    participants.conversation_id
```

Any idea?

Comment: How can a user ID for one `Participants` row be both equal to 1 and either 4 or 6? That does not make any sense

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmmm.  Here is a method using `group by` and `having`:

```
select p.conversation_id
from participants p
group by p.conversation_id
having sum(p.user_id = 1) > 0 and     -- user 1 in conversation
       sum(p.user_id in (4, 6)) > 0;   -- user 4 and/or 6 in conversation
```

Answer (score 1):

What I understand from your questions was you want to see users "4,6" involved in conversation with user_id = 1. to do so try following query.

```
 select * from (SELECT     conversations.id as conversation_id, participants.user_id as selectedUser,   GROUP_CONCAT(participants.user_id) AS participants
 FROM       `conversations` 
 INNER JOIN `participants` ON `conversations`.`id` = `participants`.`conversation_id` 
GROUP BY    participants.conversation_id ) as derivedTable 
where 
selectedUser=1 and 
(participants like '%4%' and participants like '%6%')
```

[image]

what above query does is. initially it will take all record from conversation and participants table and concat all participants agains user_id=1. then outer query checks are pretty clear to find user_id and participants have 4 and 6.